# Place view above Sliding drawer handle

Tags: android

I have an application with a sliding drawer view. My problem is that in the drawer activity layout I have a list view that reaches the bottom of the screen where the sliding drawer handle is. so the last element in the list can not be seen, because the handle overlaps it.
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved that by adding space in the bottom of my listview

By the  following steps:

1.create space_fotter.xml in the layout folder

space_fotter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/color_appBackground">
<ImageView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src = "@drawable/bg_white"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

The @drawable/bg_white it just a small white png file that I created.

2.call space_fotter.xml from your list activty class

```
View SpaceFotter = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.space_fotter, null);
```

3.add it to your listview:

```
private ListView lv;
lv =(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
lv.addFooterView(SpaceFotter );
```

Comment: simple way to do it is to add android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" to the listview